# C++ circular dependency

Tags: c++

I have an object class, and an exception class derives from it.
Now I want a method of object class throw an exception object but run into endless "base class not defined" and "incomplete type" problems. Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Code:

```
class object
{

public:
    virtual ~object(){ }

    virtual bool equals(){ throw new exception; }
    virtual int getHash(){ throw new exception; }
    virtual void getType(){ throw new exception; }
};

class exception :
    public object
{
private:
public:
    exception();
    virtual ~exception();
    virtual const char* info();
};
```

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart I tried but got "incomplete type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define the member function in the class. Define it after the two classes have been defined.

Comment: Do I have to put it into a separate cpp file?

Comment: Either that or define it as inline in the header.

Comment: Does the "inline" mean the language keyword or just put the implementations after class declarations? I tried the latter one and it works....

Comment: @babel92: **inline** is the c++ keyword that allow you to have method's implementation right at its declaration.

Comment: @user1920482 - `inline` allows multiple definitions in different translation units of the same function; without it, that would violate the One Definition Rule.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, just put the implementations of class `object` in a separate cpp file, leave only declarations in the header.

Comment: I believe in most case, putting impl in its own cpp file is the preferred way (unless for inline/templates etc).  C/C++ do not work like other language like Java/C# etc.  Putting your impl in header is going to cause you lots of problem in compilation in the future.  If you really want to always put impl together with your declaration, don't choose C/C++  :)

Comment: In fact I'm making a .NET-like framework in order to practice template programming and want to make it neat (that is, whenever I want to use it, I only need an "include") But now it seems a bit difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the exception class to inherit from the object class?  You can define the exception class before the object class in your header file if you don't want separate cpp files.

```
    class exception {  
        private:
        public:
            exception();
            // rest of your code
    };

    class object {
        public:
            virtual ~object() {}
            virtual bool equals() { throw exception(); }
            // rest of your code
    };
```

Comment: Actually, I need it inherit from the object class:)